# How to parse json in flutter with arrays of arrays?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

How to parse the json which contains array of array values using flutter. I know that this json format is not a valid but unfortunately I need to parse it.

```
   {
   ModuleEId: [
   [
   "Test Equipment - R&D",
   "GPU_0001_180 KVA Dual AC 28.5V DC"
   ],
   [
   "Test Equipment - Electronics",
   "GPU_0004_180 KVA Dual AC 28.5 V DC"
   ]
   ]
   }
```

Comment: Isn't it valid? `((((jsonDecode(string)['ModuleId'] as List)[0] as List)[0]) as String) == "Test Equipment - R&D"`

Answer (score 2):

To parse a json you can use `json.decode(jsonString)` from package `dart:convert`. But first, you need to fix the format.

In this case, you could use for example `replaceAll` method to add the double quotes.

```
String jsonString = "/*loaded json*/";
jsonString = jsonString.replaceAll('ModuleEId', '"ModuleEId"');
```

And then

```
final parsed = json.decode(jsonString);
```

Full example: [Dartpad](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/cf2fc82a77eb30a12106abc0317a28d6)

Comment: It works as expected. Thanks. Can You say how to map it to a custom model class.?

Comment: @DayaNithi I don't know how should your custom model look like. Maybe this could help: [Serializing JSON inside model classes](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/json#serializing-json-inside-model-classes).

Answer (score 0):

It is not a valid JSON, but it looks like valid YAML. You can take advantage of it.
Use `yaml` package: https://pub.dev/packages/yaml. Then convert it to JSON.

```
    String input = """
    {
     ModuleEId:
     [
       [
         "Test Equipment - R&D",
         "GPU_0001_180 KVA Dual AC 28.5V DC"
       ],
       [
         "Test Equipment - Electronics",
         "GPU_0004_180 KVA Dual AC 28.5 V DC"
       ]
     ]
    }
    """;
    var yamlDoc = loadYaml(input);
    final json = jsonEncode(yamlDoc);
    print(((((jsonDecode(json)['ModuleEId'] as List)[0] as List)[0]) as String));
```

Comment: It throws error [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(148)] Unhandled Exception: type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'String'

Comment: Are we talking about same input string? Can you copy paste above code and try? It works on my system :-)

Comment: No. Actually I tried in mobile. The above answer works thank you.